# Format SSD to APFS on Windows

Tags: windows-10, mac, ssd, multi-boot, partition-recovery

I'm Running Windows from an External Drive on Macbook Air 2019, 128GB.
I Accidentally cleared Macbook Air's Inbuilt SSD.
Whole Storage 128GB, It's currently Blank(Unassigned).

1. I tried Recovery Mode (`Cmd+R`), It didn't work.
2. I tried `Option+Cmd+R` to download from the Apple Server,
   it showed -1008f at the end.
3. I tried an external macOS bootable drive,
   No Recovery Mode, right? It tried to download from the Apple Server,
   it showed -1008f at the end.

I'm thinking of formating the drive to APFS on windows and try `Option+Cmd+R` again.
I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Windows has no support for APFS.

Comment: Can I run macOS VirtualMachine and then format that disk?

Comment: Running MacOS is anything else than Apple hardware isn't allowed per its license and is off-topic here.

Comment: According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) you can also press `Shift-Option-Command-R` to run recovery from Internet.

Comment: @ChanganAuto His computer is a "Macbook Air 2019". Why do you think that is not Apple hardware?

Comment: @ChanganAuto - formatting APFS on Windows is not against any licensing agreement - nor will it in this case actually achieve anything. It can be done with [Paragon APFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/) which would be great if it was going to gain anything, but a complete waste of $£€ 45 for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)
Formatting an external drive to APFS will not fix your issue.

You need to be able to connect to the internet - try wired ethernet instead of WiFi. As you blew away your internal drive completely, you have no source for Recovery except Internet Recovery or if you have access to another Mac on which you can make a bootable installer USB. There is no way to legitimately access a bootable installer from Windows.

Holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  with no Recovery Partition should automatically switch to Internet Recovery instead. That it doesn't already hints at connectivity issues.

If all else fails, take it to an Apple Store - they will do it for you for free.